Textarea right padding when using a horizontal scrollbar?
When creating a textarea with a horizontal scrollbar, how to enable a padding on the right side?
CSS padding works for the top right corner, but not for the right side:



textarea {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 14rem;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
<textarea>foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar</textarea>




Related: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40067466

@SyndRain I think you can post this as an answer, it clearly states the current status about this small CSS quirk.

This seems to be a known bug (Issue #40572939) specifically for textarea and have been staying open without any fix for a while in Chromium. As quoted in the issue:

This is due to the layout overflow calculation not including inline-end padding for block-level children, this may be fixed if we change our behaviour here.

For now the only solution I know all involves changing the textarea to a contenteditable similar to what @spyder1329 posted.

Interesting issue.  I would use a content editable div.


#test {
        white-space: pre;
        overflow-wrap: normal;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 5rem;
        width: 14rem;
        padding: 0.75rem;
    }
<div id="test" contenteditable="plaintext-only">foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar</div>




Do you see a solution without migrating to content-editable div? (Everything is already set up with textarea... ;))

Snippet added.
Without using a complex wrapper or adding hackish javascript code I really can't think of a more elegant solution.
Maybe someone else will stop by to post something that blows our minds.

With your snippet, there is no right-side padding when scrolled to the right, on Firefox. For you does it work? It works on Chrome though!

I slightly modified the snippet by setting contenteditable to plaintext-only.  I've tested this in Edge and Chrome but not Firefox.

Snippet has no padding-right in Firefox either (133.0.3, Ubuntu via Snap). In my own code it  momentarily bugged out and worked, but that's happened once that I saw over thousands of refreshes across a dozen different experimental attempts.
